# CS3 Flash - Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5

The .swf files are in my library and on my hard drive, why is it saying it can't find them?

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var myLoader:Loader=new Loader();
myLoader.x = 0;
myLoader.y = 100;

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movie1);
function movie1(myevent:MouseEvent):void{
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Phase1IP.swf");
    myLoader.load(myURL);
    addChild(myLoader);
}

btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movie2);
function movie2(myevent:MouseEvent):void{
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Phase2IP.swf");
    myLoader.load(myURL);
    addChild(myLoader);
}


btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movie3);
function movie3(myevent:MouseEvent):void{
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Phase3IP.swf");
    myLoader.load(myURL);
    addChild(myLoader);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an event listener to your `myLoader` to catch IO errors.  In the following example (which should not be used in Production) I'll simply trace the full URL of the file that ActionScript thinks is missing to the console...

```
var myLoader:Loader=new Loader();
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(ioError:IOErrorEvent){
  trace(ioError.text);
});
```

Now, when you click on your button, your console should display something like...

`Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: file:///C|/.../Phase1IP.swf`

If you determine that `Phase1IP.swf` is located at the URL traced to the console it *still* won't load, there may be another issue to explore.

Comment: Thank you I will try that. So the event listener and trace will actually show where the file is located?

Comment: Okay the trace did find the file location.  Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: file:///C|/Users/MST/Desktop/Animation%20for%20the%20Web/Phase%204/Phase1IP.swf

Comment: So that means there has to be another issue somewhere else.

Comment: Could it be because there is a folder on my desktop labeled Animation for the Web, then a folder inside of that labeled Phase 1 IP, and a folder inside of that one labeled Phase 1 IP?  Maybe the path is to complicated or to long.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that file is there?  Don't worry about the path being "too complication"?

Comment: Okay I thought that the path to the file was to complicated, so the folder that was inside of the other folder I deleted. Bu the IOeventviewer is still showing that it is looking for the second folder which doesn't exist anymore.  What other problem should I look for now?

Comment: Yes the file is there.

Comment: I got it figured out thanks to LDMS, all the files have to be in the same folder or directory as the .fla  I went to publish settings and found that only my (Main.fla) was there so it was looking for the other .swf files in that location and they were'n there. But since I put them there it works now. Thanks guys for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Make absolutely certain your file path is correct.**
   If you don't supply a path to a URLRequest, it will assume the resource is in the same directory as the current .fla you're working with (or more precisely wherever you have the .swf publishing to, which by default will be the same directory as the .fla).
2. Make sure your security sandbox settings are correct.

   To check them, go to your publish settings, under "ADVANCED" there should be a select box labeled "Local Playback Security" - make sure this is set to **"Access Local Files Only"**
3. Save yourself the headache next time and listen for the appropriate potential errors before loading a file:

   ```
   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
   loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError); 
   loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError); 
   loader.load(request);
   ```

Comment: I will do that, thank you very much for all your help. I am just a beginner in Flash and action script.