# actionscript 3 code works well locally but not in my server

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a block of code in actionscript3 embedded in flash to measure the ping.
When I execute it via html locally, it functions well.
but when I execute it via my server, the second http post does not be executed,except this, everything is fine.

```
import JSON;
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("xxxxxxx");
var myLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onload);
myLoader.load(myRequest);

function onload(evt:Event):void
{
var obj:Object = JSON.parse(myLoader.data);
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ldrStatus);

var url:String = obj.url; 
var src:String;
var limit:int = obj.measurementTimes;

var time_start:Number;
var time_stop:Number;
var i:int = 0;
var TimesArray:Array = new Array();

ping();

function ping():void
    {
     i = 0;
     postToServer(JSON.stringify(obj));////THIS ONE WORKS WELL////////////////////////
     doThePing();
    }

function postToServer(content:String)
  {
      var url:String = "xxxxx";
      var Postrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
      Postrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

      var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
      requestVars.myobj = content;
      Postrequest.data = requestVars;

      var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
      loader.load(Postrequest);

  }


function doThePing():void
 {
   src = url + '?random-no-cache=' + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16);
   time_start = getTimer();
   ldr.load(new URLRequest(src));
 }

function ldrStatus(evt:Event):void
{
    time_stop = getTimer();
    TimesArray[i] = time_stop - time_start;
      obj.task[0].value = obj.task[0].value + TimesArray[i]+ " ";
    trace("got response in", obj.task[0].value, "ms");

     obj.task[0].IsFinished = true;
     var objJson:String = JSON.stringify(obj);
     postToServer(objJson);////////THIS ONE DOES NOT BE EXECUTED WHEN ON THE SERVER////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

}

Comment: the first post work fine but the second does not work

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25874572/1457439  - point 2 especially.

Comment: it does not point my problem out because the first post works which means that the security setting is okay so I think may be some usage of the event but i do not know what kind of problem....

Comment: At any rate, attach error listeners (see that same post I linked to) so you can at least find out what's happening. in your `postToServer` you don't even have a complete listener so how are you measuring success?

Comment: Yeah, adding listeners to your loader will definitely help to post the problem :) Is your swf and the URL you're posting to on the same domain ? Are you sending some huge data in your second POST (everything over 2000 characters already might cause problems) ?